# Is there a way to insert paragraph breaks inside of \texttt block?

Tags: line-breaking, paragraphs, typewriter

The following source code compiles just fine:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\begin{document}
\texttt{
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet        
    Lorem Lorem    
}
\end{document}
```

However, the following produces an error:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\begin{document}
\texttt{
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet

    Lorem Lorem    
}
\end{document}
```

Sometimes the error message is:

```
 Paragraph ended before \text@command was complete.
```

Is there someway to allow paragraph breaks inside of a `\texttt` block?

Comment: Off-topic: try to [avoid the `minimal` class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42114/why-should-the-minimal-class-be-avoided).

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 6):

Use the global font switch inside a group instead of the command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
{\ttfamily
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet

    Lorem Lorem    
}
\end{document}
```

[image]